# Python2.7 -Zip and password protect file

Tags: python-2.7

Can I do zip and password protect the zip file using Python2.7?
I have done it using pyzipper in python3.7 but here I want 2.7 as this is modification of existing script.
I tried most option over internet and nothing helped.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
This is my first post and sorry if I miss anything.